# How can I compare a UTC date created in Javascript to a UTC date in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime, utc

I'm trying to create a UTC date in JavaScript on one server, and pass it via URL querystring to another server, where C# can take that querystring, recognize it as a date and compare it to a new C# UTC date - and it's proving trickier that I though (unless I'm just having one of those days). I don't see any other questions on stackoverflow asking this (in the 'similar titles' or 'similar questions' lists that show while typing a question).

To create the data in JavaScript I'm using the following, based on [this w3schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp):

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var  day = currentDate.getUTCDate();
var month = currentDate.getUTCMonth();
var year = currentDate.getUTCFullYear();
var hours = currentDate.getUTCHours();
var minutes = currentDate.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = currentDate.getUTCSeconds();
var milliseconds = currentDate.getUTCMilliseconds();

var expiry = Date.UTC(month,day,year,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds);
```

the results looks like this `1311871476074`

So, in C# how do I take this value from the querystring and

1. convert it into a proper date, and
2. compare it to a C# based UTC DateTime variable?

Any tips, corrections in my logic/code or links to articles would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin

***UPDATE**

Both the answers below helped me resolve my issue: Luke helped with the C# side of things, and Ray helped with the JavaScript - unfortunately I can't mark them both as answers, but I wish I could!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JavaScript `UTC` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) returns the number of milliseconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970. To convert those milliseconds back to a `DateTime` in C# you just need to add them onto that original "epoch":

```
string rawMilliseconds = Request.QueryString["expiry"];

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawMilliseconds))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Expiry is null or empty!");

long milliseconds;
if (!long.TryParse(rawMilliseconds, out milliseconds))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to parse expiry!");

DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

DateTime expiry = epoch.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 4):

A datetime object represents an instant in time and is usually represented internally as the number of milliseconds since the epoch.  In JavaScript to get this value for the current time it is easier to use

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Now you just have a number (or a string containing a number) which you can pass to your C# application and construct a DateTime object from.

For that I can refer you to [C# convert UTC int to DateTime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565023/c-convert-utc-int-to-datetime-object) (Jon Skeet has an answer for it.) :)

Comment: Luke's answer above is what I was looking for. I didn't mention it in my question, but the server executing the JavaScript is based in the UK, while the .NET server accepting the 'expiry' querystring is in the US, so using UTC Dates is critical in both JavaScipt and C#, so .getTime() wouldn't work for me in this case.

Comment: No worries.  But be aware that in JavaScript, `getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch and is completely time zone independent.  Many developers prefer to do all time processing using this epoch time internally and never bring timezones into play until it is time to display them (or if they need to do calculations like "one month ago").  Epoch times are not UTC, nor in any timezone.  They are just numbers representing a specific instant in time.  Worth mastering. :)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Ray. I'd been poking around JavaScript all morning and seen `.getUTCyear` vs. `.getYear`, so figured when I saw you mentioned `.getTime` that this would be the current time in 'regular' format.. turns out, `var expiry = new Date.getTime();` is exactly what I needed, in combination with Luke's C# info above. Thanks both!